# Call a function of a library, outside the library

Tags: javascript

I have a library that runs in a `(function() { ... }) ();` scheme ...

```
// mylibrary.js
(function() {
    function myfunc() { alert('hello'); };

    if (...) 
      return;

    // do something

}) ();
```

... that I use in a HTML page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<body>  
  <div>Bonjour</div>

  <script src="mylibrary.js"></script>

  <script>
    myfunc();  // scope error !
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**How to call the function `myfunc()` *outside the library* ?**
Should I change the `(function() { ... }) ();` scheme ? (that I used to be able to do some `return` inside the library)

**What is the most common practice?**

Comment: This is the library i'm speaking about (it's mine and needs to be improved of course!) : https://github.com/josephernest/bigpicture.js/blob/master/bigpicture.js

Comment: as written, you can't. you can publish the functions you need to window, an internal object, or use an exports-bsed exporter like commonJS

Comment: @dandavis What is the most common practice? (I'd like to avoid third party tools/libraries for exporting)?

Comment: there is no best. you can return an object and assign the outside, like Born2Code's, or you can use a commonJS pattern, or even and AMD pattern if you like async. personally, i think that, for browsers, the module shown by Born2Code is closest to what i would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the **[Revealing Module Pattern](https://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern/)**:

```
var module = (function() { // Self invoking function
    var privateVariable = 42; // This variable is private to the module.
    var publicFunction = function() { console.log(42); } // Still not public

    return {
        myPublic: publicFunction // Now it is, notice optional the name change!
    }
})(); //Call itself.

module.myPublic(); // Call by the new name.
```

In this case, the function is executed and an Object is returned (so `module` is now an Object), and you simply call functions which are members of that object.

Comment: Thanks @SecondRikudo for having introduced me to the topic of Patterns. Do you think this variation is correct : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397099/slight-variation-of-the-revealing-module-pattern ?

Answer (score 1):

here is how you should do it.

```js
var myApp = (function() {
  var stuff = []; //private

  return { //exposed to public
    myfunc: function(values) {
      alert('You said: ' + values);
    }
  }
}());

myApp.myfunc('Test Me');
```

Comment: To improve organization of my code / library, can you mention which part of code should be the library, how to call the library from the HTML, etc. ? Thanks in advance @Born2Code !

Answer (score -1):

If you mean for you function to be globally available, then you can assign it to the `window` object:

```
window.myfunc = myfunc;
```

This is what Mixpanel does:

http://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.js

Comment: No. Add one one property to the global object (i.e., a namespace) through which a library is accessed .

Comment: In which line of http://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.js is the export with `window`?

Comment: Can you explain what global object are you talking about @orb ? Maybe can you provide an answer? These terms (namespace, property to the global object are not so clear for me yet)

Comment: Sorry @Basj, I was incorrect about the [link](http://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.js).  Mixpanel assigns to the `window` object in a more indirect way than what I have shown.