# Slight variation of the Revealing Module Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, javascript, revealing-module-pattern

Is it good practice to use, instead of this [Revealing Module Pattern](https://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern/) ...

```
var MyModule = ( function() {
  function Method1() { alert( 'method1' ); }
  function Method2() { Method1(); alert( 'method2' ); }
  function Method3() { Method1(); alert( 'method3' ); }
  function Method4() { Method1(); alert( 'method4' ); }
  return { Method1 : Method1,    // these
           Method2 : Method2,    // lines
           Method3 : Method3,    // are 
           Method4 : Method4 };  // redundant...
} )();

MyModule.Method1(); 
MyModule.Method2();
```

... this slight variation:

```
var MyModule = {};
( function() {
  var Method1 = MyModule.Method1 = function () { alert( 'method1' ); };
  var Method2 = MyModule.Method2 = function () { Method1(); alert( 'method2' ); };
  var Method3 = MyModule.Method3 = function () { Method1(); alert( 'method3' ); };
  var Method4 = MyModule.Method4 = function () { Method1(); alert( 'method4' ); };
} )();

MyModule.Method1();
MyModule.Method2();
```

**Is it 100% the same at the end? Would this considered as good practice?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the same. If you were to rename your module at any time or wish to use it in a different name, you won't be able to.

Also, by returning the object at the end of the array, you make it perfectly clear what's exposed out of the object.

Comment: You *can* rename it with the second form, it's just that it's a global search and replace rather than one edit. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it 100% the same at the end?

The end result is the same.

> Would this considered as good practice?

That's primarily a matter of opinion. Your examples are two of several variations on the RMP, both valid.

A third variation commonly seen is similar to your second, but has a specific purpose:

```
var MyModule = function(mod) {
  var Method1 = mod.Method1 = function () { alert( 'method1' ); };
  var Method2 = mod.Method2 = function () { Method1(); alert( 'method2' ); };
  var Method3 = mod.Method3 = function () { Method1(); alert( 'method3' ); };
  var Method4 = mod.Method4 = function () { Method1(); alert( 'method4' ); };
  return mod;
}(typeof MyModule === "undefined" ? {} : MyModule);
```

The purpose there is to allow *adding to* a module that's already defined, but creating it if it's not already defined.

Comment: Oh I thought the second one would be considered as *less verbose* as it doesn't need to `return` something at the end, etc. ;)
If you had to do a choice, which one of these 2 (or maybe another pattern?) would you use for https://github.com/josephernest/bigpicture.js/blob/master/bigpicture.js ?

Comment: @Basj: Actually, it isn't more verbose. But if you're asking for an opinion, with modern engines I probably wouldn't use either. I'd probably use something more similar to the third option above (not exactly that, probably, but similar).

Answer (score 1):

Your first and second variations are not the same. The first is what I would call a "self-contained" IIFE -- the body of the IIFE does its job without assuming any information about the world outside the IIFE. The second variation of yours assumes that there is a `MyModule` object in the outside world. While that is a small assumption, I prefer to write all my IIFEs in a self-contained manner.

The second variation can be made self-contained with a slight modification:

```
var MyModule = {};
( function(MyModule) {
  var Method1 = MyModule.Method1 = function () { alert( 'method1' ); };
  var Method2 = MyModule.Method2 = function () { Method1(); alert( 'method2' ); };
  var Method3 = MyModule.Method3 = function () { Method1(); alert( 'method3' ); };
  var Method4 = MyModule.Method4 = function () { Method1(); alert( 'method4' ); };
} )(MyModule);

MyModule.Method1();
MyModule.Method2();
```

By passing in the created external object as a parameter to the IIF, the code inside the IIFE no longer makes assumptions about the outside world, and can be more easily moved around to different places inside your code base.

However, you also asked

> Would this be considered as good practice?

My answer to this is that **you shouldn't use the Revealing Module Pattern at all**! The Revealing Module Pattern has an important [defect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925720/what-is-meant-by-public-function-cant-be-overridden-if-a-patch-is-necessary/21932064#21932064) that makes me consider it an [anti-pattern](http://slides.com/i-linkuo/the-revealing-module-is-an-anti-pattern#/), so I would recommend against using it at all. Stick to the original module pattern, not the Revealing Module.

Comment: For future reference : IIFE = http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression